# Who are these superheroes?

Tags: comics, character-identification

I realize the DCnU has changed but I am having trouble recognizing some of the people in this image. I recognize Guy Gardner (Green Lantern) and Booster Gold. I assume that one of them is a remnant of the Batmen from Batman Incorporated.

- Wasn't Batman Incorporated retconned after Flashpoint? If they weren't, does this mean Batman still sanctions their operations (and licenses his Bat icon)?
- I admit to having stopped reading Firestorm back when he became a fire elemental (Ugh). But I can still recognize his costume. (When did he become a Black guy?) The woman bears a strong resemblance to Firehawk with a costume change. Anybody know why their costumes look the same now?
- Who are the fellow with the Mohawk, the woman dangling from the bottom of the stone hand and the red guy with the staff?

[image]

Comment: Well if Thaddeus can't recognize a comic superhero... we're doomed !

Comment: I am hoping this is just a case of what I call "reboot identity crisis". If you don't read a particular book, you may not recognize characters who are either second-stringers or have been made unrecognizable due to new writers. What I hope is someone is reading this book and can enlighten me. Then I will add them to my mental superhero database and we are all good.

Comment: Ok, I'm reassured :P

Comment: [This page](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fury_of_Firestorm_Vol_1_9) should help **significantly** in the identification. It lists the characters in the issue with that cover.

Comment: I don't see Firestorm as black, he just looks tan in that shot. I suppose you could argue that he is light skinned black, but usually comics make an effort to distinguish. For example, lips and noses are usually fuller/wider in black depictions.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - Wish I'd seen your comment before I commenced with teh google. Interestingly, it appears the photo that is in the question is the one depicted as "alternative" cover art, given the location of the artist stamp in the lower left rather than on the right in the cover.

Comment: @JohnP Well, I decided to write up an answer. I might later include some images from dc.wikia to help confirm identifications. Zachary's reference to dc.wikia brought me to do a bit of searching there and using Thaddeus' ID of Firehawk brought me to that character's page which had a **short** list of appearances: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Firehawk_%28Prime_Earth%29/Appearances . One of the five cover images showed the fist, which linked to that comic's page. Bingo.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - That's a pretty good corroboration, though, that two independent searches came up with the same conclusions. Upvoted your answer. :D

Comment: Batman doesn't license the bat symbol (as seen with Batwoman using it despite his wishes), he just funds/supports the members of Batman Inc...which was a dark point in Batman's history

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [Fury of Firestorm Vol 1 #9 page](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fury_of_Firestorm_Vol_1_9) (the image is the cover art for that issue):

- The blue-skinned mohawk person is [Kevin Kho/O.M.A.C.](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Kho_%28Prime_Earth%29) (as [Zachary's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39135/) notes).
  [image]
- The man on the ground is (as Thaddeus guessed) [Firestorm (Jason Rusch)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jason_Rusch_%28New_Earth%29) (He appears to be somewhat dark-skinned and distinct from another [Firestorm (Ronald Raymond)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ronald_Raymond_%28New_Earth%29), who also appears in that issue [so my identification may not be correct].)

  [image]
- The character with the Batman symbol is [Batwing (David Zavimbe)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/David_Zavimbe_%28Prime_Earth%29). [image]
- The woman on the ground is (again as Thaddeus guessed) [Firehawk](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Firehawk_%28Prime_Earth%29). [image]
- The character in the gold and blue costume with a star on the chest is (again as Thaddeus surmised) [Booster Gold (Michael Jon Carter)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Jon_Carter_%28New_Earth%29).
  [image]
- The blonde dangling woman is presumably [Godiva (Dorcas Leigh)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Dorcas_Leigh_%28New_Earth%29). [image]
- The red-skinned character is [August General in Iron (Fang Zhifu)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fang_Zhifu_%28New_Earth%29). [image]
- The Green Lantern is (again as Thaddeus surmised) [Guy Gardner](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Guy_Gardner_%28Prime_Earth%29). [image]

Comment: Godiva? August General in Iron? OMAC? The last time I saw OMAC he didn't look like THAT! Never heard of the August General in Iron, not sure I have ever heard of Godiva either. Nice work, Paul. Any idea why Firehawk and Firestorm are wearing similar duds? Does Batman Incorporated still fund Batwing (whichever one he is?) And there are two people wearing the Firestorm name???

Comment: @Thaddeus Perhaps you are thinking of [Buddy Blank/O.M.A.C.](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Buddy_Blank_%28Earth-AD%29)? Not a comics person (just jumped off of Zachary's answer), so I can't provide further info (the page did say the Batwing was David Zavimbe). As for multiple Firestorms, the page indicates the villains were "Rogue Firestorms" and [this image](http://images.wikia.com/marvel_dc/images/b/bd/Firestorm_group.jpg) is shows many Firestorms--but that is **not** Paris, where the issue is sited--; but again I am not a comics person.

Comment: @Thaddeus August General first appeared briefly in *52*, which I highly recommend if you haven't read it before.  It meanders at times, but is overall a great limited series.

Comment: I have made this community wiki to encourage anyone with the knowledge to answer the non-ID aspects of the question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a cover photo from [Fury of Firestorm V1 #9](http://www.boosterrific.com/comics/issues/?fme109_Fury-of-Firestorm,-The%3a-The-Nuclear-Men-Volume-1-Issue-9)

The guy with the staff is August General in Iron, mohawk is O.M.A.C., it's either Batman or Batwing, and I believe the girl with the hair is Godiva. All of them are from the short lived reboot Justice League International.

I did find this [random forum posting](http://www.bleedingcool.com/forums/comic-book-forum/46092-booster-gold-return-mystery-jli-woman.html) which shows Godiva? with a black jumpsuit instead of a white.

Comment: I believe he goes by Batwing, he's a member of Batman Inc., but I'm not sure if that's the new Batwing (Lucious Fox's son) or the original.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that the blue mohawk guy is [O.M.A.C](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/omac)

Comment: Almost certainly this is [Kevin Kho/O.M.A.C.](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kevin_Kho_%28Prime_Earth%29) based on the character list on [this page](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fury_of_Firestorm_Vol_1_9) and similarity of appearance in picture on the character's dc.wikia page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that would be [Firestorm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm_%28comics%29), from "The Fury of Firestorm: The Nuclear Man".